# explain why is_single doesn't work

Tags: single

I am playing around with template hierarchy. I have uploaded stock 2012 theme and deleted page.php and single.php. I found that when I visit a blog post and click the the post reply link to leave a comment, the comment form doesn't show. So I copied comments_template() function out of single.php and pasted it into content.php inside the is_single conditional that looks like this

```
    <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>
 //added the comments template here
 comments_template( '', true);
        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
```

from that, I would expect the comments template to show but it does not. It did however show up when I added the is_single conditional to the index.php loop

Why would it not work in the

```
 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());
```

Comment: the `comments_template()` code should be in the 'if' section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to display comments for a single post that has comments disabled.

You should find `if ( comments_open() )` statement just one line below.

Paste your code there and it will work just fine:

```
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                <div class="comments-link">
                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .comments-link -->
                <?php comments_template( '', true); ?>
            <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
```

Also, I can't find PHP starting & ending tag in your example, but I suppose it's just a typo? :)

Cheers,
I hope it helps.